# Are there more "example-based" manuals or docs about expl3?

Tags: luatex, expl3, latex3

I'm interested in learning `expl3` because allows flexibility in macro writing and, unlike Lua, it is supported by most TeX engines. I've read the following questions and answers with respect to `expl3` documentation when searching for examples of code, not as helpful as I expected:

- [Example packages using expl3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341325/example-packages-using-expl3)
- [Forthcoming LaTeX3 User Manual](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260484/forthcoming-latex3-user-manual) (there's no actual user manual)

The questions have 3 o 4 years posted and the documentation so far is a bit sparse, I think. So, I want to know if there are manuals or similar documents more "example-based" of `expl3` or written at a slower pace.

Comment: IIRC, `expl3.pdf` is a (gentle) introduction, then you can dive in  `interface3.pdf`.  “Little examples” are in great number on this site and there are also examples in `interface3.pdf`. I believe you would get better help if you asked a specific question concerning a specific point you don't understand. :-) (all this assumes you have a small background in TeX programming, e.g. having read and understood a good part of the TeXbook, and practiced a bit writing of TeX macros, because the `expl3` docs assume you understand important TeX concepts: tokens, expansion, macros, boxes, modes...)

Comment: I'm sitting here literally wasting hours searching for these "little examples" and they are proving nearly impossible to find for my needs. There is a desperate need for a coherent collection of examples for non-experts. Existing documentation is written for the expert developers and is quite incomprehensible without concrete examples.

Comment: There's this https://www.alanshawn.com/latex3-tutorial/ But I agree that someone should make a more extensive tutorial about expl3 syntax including simple examples that work.